# Having problems with HC-05 and three relays

Tags: bluetooth, relay

I'm trying to control three relays with the Arduino Uno rev3 and a HC-05 bluetooth module from Elecfreaks.

I've wrote this code:

```
// the comments are the part of the code that I use to replace the Serial by default to be able to use the HC-05 module 
//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
int relay1 = 2;
int relay2 = 3;
int relay3 = 4;
int relay1estatus = 0;
int relay2estatus = 0;
int relay3estatus = 0;
char command;
//SoftwareSerial bluetooth(5,6);

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600); //bluetooth.begin(9600);
 pinMode(relay1, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(relay2, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(relay3, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
 digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);
 digitalWrite(relay3, LOW);
}

void loop() {
 while(Serial.available() > 0){ //bluetooth.available()
  command = (byte)Serial.read(); //(byte)bluetooth.read();
  Serial.println(command); //bluetooth.println(command)

  if (command == 'a'){
   if (relay1estatus == 0){
    digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
    relay1estatus = 1;
   }else{
    digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
    relay1estatus = 0;
   }
  }

 if (command == 'b'){ 
  if (relay2estatus == 0){
   digitalWrite(relay2, HIGH);
   relay2estatus = 1;
  }else{
   digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);
   relay2estatus = 0;
  }
 }

 if (command == 'c'){
  if (relay3estatus == 0){
   digitalWrite(relay3, HIGH);
   relay3estatus = 1;
  }else{
   digitalWrite(relay3, LOW);
   relay3estatus = 0;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

The problem is that this code works perfectly using the Arduino IDE serial monitor, but when I try it using instead of the default serial methods, the SoftwareSerial ones it doesn't work.

Doesn't work in a very strange way because I can switch one by one the relays between on or off but, when I have two of them activated seems like freezes, I can't switch the third one on or off and neither I can switch the other two again.

To send the 'commands' through bluetooth I use the Bluetooth Terminal app available in the PlayStore.
(I've just posted the same question in stackoverflow but now I think here's the best place to ask it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem with the code indicated for bluetooth; if that code is indeed ok, then probably you should look for hardware issues;  first, look for low +5V when multiple relays are turned on.  (Attach a voltmeter or a scope to +5, see if it changes when a second relay comes on, etc.)  Second, look (with a storage scope) for glitches when the relays switch.  If you don't have a storage scope, try testing with a separate power supply for the relays.  (Tie the grounds of things together, but give the Arduino and the HC-05 +V that's isolated from relay +V.)

More seriously, your code is overweight.  For example, replace

```
   if (relay1estatus == 0){
    digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
    relay1estatus = 1;
   } else {
    digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
    relay1estatus = 0;
   }
```

with

```
    relay1estatus = 1 - relay1estatus;
    digitalWrite(relay1, relay1estatus);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This issue have been driving me mad for some days because I was sure it wasn't a software problem.. also I had the module connected at 3V and that cause some problems with the power as I saw, so I've connected the relays and the bluetooth in  parallel to 5V and I've also added two capacitors just in case.